# How to print columns of two tables with "one to many" relationship in an html table?

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, pdo

I have a database with two tables and the two tables have "one to many " relationship .
1st table called data with columns(name , phone , personid).
2nd table called links with columns(linkid , link , personid).

Personid is the forigne key , I want to print 3 columns from the two tables (name , phone , links) where links is each user links .

So I want the table to be something like that :

```
echo "<table>";    
echo "<tr><th>Name</th> <th>Phone</th> <th>Links</th></tr>";

while ($row = $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>".$row['name']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['phone']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['links']."</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

And the table looks like that :

Name       Phone      Links

John       67655       link1

```
          link2  
           ...
```

Comment: So, Where is the query?

Comment: Which query you mean ? the one in the loop or what ?

Comment: `$result` query

Answer (score 1):

Your query should be like

```
SELECT data.personid, name, phone, link FROM data JOIN links ON data.personid = links.personid
```

Then in PHP:

```
$data = [];

foreach($results as $result) {
    if (!isset($data[$result['personid']])) {
        $data[$result['personid']] = [
            'name' => $result['name'],
            'phone' => $result['phone'],
            'links' => [],
        ];
    }

    $data[$result['personid']]['links'][] = $result['link'];
}
```

And later in HTML:

```
 echo '<table>';
 foreach ($data as $row) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>".$row['name']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['phone']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".implode(', ', $row['links'])."</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
 }

 echo "</table>";
```

Comment: Warning: Illegal string offset 'personid' Warning: Illegal string offset 'personid' 
Warning: Illegal string offset 'name' 
Warning: Illegal string offset 'phone'
Warning: Illegal string offset 'personid' 
Warning: Illegal string offset 'link'

Comment: @Sam make sure `$results` are actual database results and not string.

Comment: There are many warnings , Please if there is something is not clear in what I said in the question , I would clear it

Comment: $state = $connect->prepare("SELECT data.personid, name, phone, link FROM data JOIN links ON data.personid = links.personid");
$state->execute();
$results = $state->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

Comment: @Sam Use `fetchAll`, not `fetch`. Later will return single row